# Char not being saved to file correctly

Tags: c++-cli

I want to save the contents of a ComboBox to a file. The code below correctly shows a MessageBox with "Marker 4" (the text in the ComboBox), but the saved file contains "03038D8C" instead of "Marker 4", I guess this is the memory address of the variable or something similar? How can I correctly output the "Marker 4"-string to the file?

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  cmbMarker;
private: System::String^ strMarkerText; 

...

strMarkerText = this->cmbMarker->Text;

...

ofstream myfile;

WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wname = PtrToStringChars(strMarkerText);
FindFirstFile(wname, &data);

::MessageBox(0, wname, L"Marker inserted", MB_OK);

myfile <<"=====MARKER '" << wname << "' INSERTED AT " << datetime << " =====" << endl;
```

[There may be more than this wrong with this snippet, I'm not from a C++/CLI background but appreciate your help! There are no compiler errors and the code runs fine except for the issue described above, i.e. that not the cleartext-string-contents are written to the file ("Marker 4"), but "03038D8C".]

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I think you'll have more luck with the `c++-cli` tag. :)

Comment: Yes, I just realized that this is not native c++ but contains some of Microsoft's ever-wonderful fairy dust :-)! Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting the `System::String^` to a `std:str` and directly inserted this (rather than converting it to a `wchar_t`).

The mix between native c++ and CLI is because I'm building on a SDK-example built in native c++, but wanted to add a form to it (in Visual Studio 2008), which turned it into this "mix". I realize that that's not optimal, but so far, it seems to work :-)! I'll try to only use CLI-equivalents if I run into any more errors going forward. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a narrow stream with a wide string. Use `std::wofstream` instead of `std::ofstream` and it should work fine.

That being said, I agree with @jonsca -- why drag iostreams into a C++/CLI app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your application's requirements, but have you considered using the .NET "equivalents" of the functions, like `System::IO::Directory` methods (specifically `GetFiles` in place of `FindFirstFile`), and the `System::IO::StreamWriter` in place of the `ofstream` object?  This way the code in this section jives with the CLR portion of your code.

I know that's not precisely what you were asking for, but I have a feeling that the pointer in your code might need to be handled differently, and I'm unsure if would have to be marshaled across the managed/unmanaged barrier.